# Desingularization of the standard Cremona involution of $\mathbb P^2$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, blowup, birational-geometry

Consider the birational map $\chi$ given by the blow up of the points $(1:0:0)$, $(0:1:0)$, and $(0:0:1)$ of $\mathbb P^2$, followed by the contraction of the strict transforms of the three lines passing through two of the above points. I would like to show that the proper transform by $\chi$ of the linear system of lines is the linear system of conics passing through $(1:0:0)$, $(0:1:0)$, and $(0:0:1)$.

Thank you in advance!

Edit : If possible without writing the maps explicitly in coordinates.

Comment: Write the map explicitly in coordinates.

Comment: @sacha I did, thank you anyway. I am looking for à more conceptual proof if possible.

Answer (score 1):

A generic line $\ell$ cuts each of the three contracted lines in one point. Thus the proper  transform $L$ of it passes through the contraction points. It is smooth on the contractions points because it cuts each of the contracted lines transversally and just one time. Thus $L$ is smooth everywhere.

In order to compute its degree it suffices to remark that it intersects each the proper transform of the exceptional divisors  of the first blow up (which is a line) only in two points. Thus $L$ is a conic (Bezout).

I hope that this is conceptual enough.

Otherwise, use intersection theory on surfaces and you will obtain the same result.